# Scaling function in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, and let $a>0$. Let $g(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x)=f(ax)$. Is it necessarily true that $g(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g$ is the composition of two $C^\infty$ functions, as such it is of class $C^\infty$. Think about the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

$g=f\circ \left(x\mapsto ax\right)$

And you know that $f_1,f_2 \in C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)\implies f_1\circ f_2 \in C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)$

Note that $g(x)\in \Bbb R$. It's a number, as opposed to $g=x\mapsto g(x)$ which is a function.